# Derived ObservationCollection does not trigger UI render

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui

New to .NET MAUI

Although, the derived `CompletedTodos` list does look to update (which I did confirm with logs), I have no clue why it (`CompletedTodos`) does not trigger a UI render.

```cs
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(CompletedTodos))]
ObservableCollection<TODO> todos = new();

public ObservableCollection<TODO> CompletedTodos =>
 new ObservableCollection<TODO>(Todos.Where(todo => todo.IsCompleted));
```

```xml
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CompletedTodos}"/>
```

Also, is this the right way to go about doing this or would this need to be down with a Behavior/Converter?

Comment: Every time you get `CompletedTogos`, you return a new collection, since you're always creating a new one. `ObservableCollection` is designed so that you create it once and then update it incrementally.

Comment: You need to subscribe to the `OnPropertyChanged` events for each TODO in your parent collection watching for `IsCompleted` changes raising `OnPropertyChanged(CompletedTodos))` accordingly.

Comment: You can make a self-answer for this case.